# How can I eliminate wine application options from Thunar's context menu?

Tags: wine, xfce, thunar, file-association, context-menu

I have Xfce and in Thunar file association are changing randomly, to wine applications
like jpeg and png to Internet Explorer and mp3 to Windows Media Player. I change it back to  `gpicview` and `Totem` and after a while, when I click on the file it starts up wine again (which takes forever to load, and IE doesn't even work, and gives an error when it loads).

How can I make my file association changes permanent, and stop them changing to wine software?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very useful [wine FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-0889dfe8795340015e07cb12e8f26f701012d534) contains details on how to clean the open with menu. I can confirm that it works safely on Xfce and will on any other desktop environment, as the locations that `wine` installs the items to are standard locations for those types of files as delineated at [freedesktop.org](http://standards.freedesktop.org/).

The commands below are from the [Wine FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-0889dfe8795340015e07cb12e8f26f701012d534) and do safely remove all open-with entries from the context menu, but they do not remove any wine entries from the applications menu, which I think is just what you want. If you need to see what they will remove, place `echo` before the `rm` command, and it will list the changes. You should run each command individually and not copy and paste the whole block, in case you make a mistake.

```
rm -f ~/.local/share/mime/packages/x-wine*
rm -f ~/.local/share/applications/wine-extension*
rm -f ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/*/*/application-x-wine-extension*
rm -f ~/.local/share/mime/application/x-wine-extension*
```

It should also be said that when you install a `wine` program, further new entries will be created, so these commands will need to be run again. The only way to permanently stop the creation of these items is to disable `winemenubuilder`, but that also affects application menu items and not just the open with menu, so you might not want to do that. See the [wine FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-c847a3ded88bac0e61aae0037fa7dbd4c7ae042a) for more details on that.

If you want to run the commands above after installing a new `wine` program, it would be best to put them in a script, make it executable (`chmod u+x`) and bind it to a shortcut key. Then you can run the script regularly and keep the open with menu clear of `wine` entries at all times.