# How can I get rid of wine menu entries when wine packages are not uninstalled?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I prefer to use PlayOnLinux to configure wine and manage prefixes.

PlayOnLinux requires wine packages to be installed, but I won't use default `/home/$USER/.wine` prefix. So I deleted default prefix but can't get rid of default menu entries.
If I delete them manually they are recreated, and occasional click on them will recreate default `.wine`.

Is there right way to hide all default wine entries?

Answer (score 0):

**Introduction**

Whenever you make a new WINEPREFIX menu entries and context menu entries are recreated automatically; your default `.wine` prefix will even be recreated, as you know, if `winecfg` is run and it the prefix doesn't exist.

Even though you are probably using different versions of `wine` and not just the system `wine` in `playonlinux`, removing system `wine` will probably take `playonlinux` with it, so there are some better alternatives that will stop `wine` regenerating menu entries all the time.

**Possible Solutions**

I have found that there are really two distinct ways of dealing with the issue:

**a)** Refer to the [wine FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-c847a3ded88bac0e61aae0037fa7dbd4c7ae042a) and permanently disable the `winemenubuilder` application, although that would generate quite a lot of error messages if you used default `wine` to install programs rather than `playonlinux` in the future. The alternative ways of dealing with `winemenubuilder` are detailed in the FAQ, such as disabling it when a particular new application is installed or disabling it for all programs to be installed by placing an override in `winecfg`.

**OR**

**b)** Just keep deleting the created menu entries by placing the commands below in a script and running it regularly. They are from the [wine FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-cf92baf0d9ee0ef112a680b45ac21805caaf9c0a), and you should be **careful** if you use them and make sure you don't make any typos. The commands below will remove `wine` applications (but not `playonlinux` ones) from your menus.

Here is the full list of commands from the [wine FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-cf92baf0d9ee0ef112a680b45ac21805caaf9c0a); use with caution and avoid typos:

```
rm -f ~/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*  
rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/wine  
rm -f ~/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
```

**If** you wish to see what will be removed, you can use `printf` with command one and three above to list the items (You can examine the directory mentioned in command two manually if you wish). As an example,

```
printf '%s\n' ~/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
```

will format the list of items nicely so it is easily readable:

```
/home/mike/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine-Programs-ViewNX 2-ViewNX 2 Help.menu
/home/mike/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine-Programs-ViewNX 2-ViewNX 2.menu
/home/mike/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine-Programs-ViewNX 2-ViewNX 2 Readme.menu
```

**Conclusion**

In short, it is up to you which option you choose to use to solve your problem, but I personally think that the simplest way is to place the commands from the wine FAQ in a script and run it periodically.

In addition, for a general discussion of how to remove `wine` context menu entries, which you may also be interested in, see my answer here:

- [How can I eliminate wine application options from Thunar's context menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185458/how-can-i-eliminate-wine-application-options-from-thunars-context-menu/277666#277666)

which is applicable not just to `Thunar` and Xfce, but all desktop environments that adhere to XDG standards.